# Start Before End

Tags: regex

### This is a quiz exercise

Only match lines with the text start, unless the text end is before that (end may or may not be in the string). Match: `ssstarttt line` And don't match `line_end start`

I tried the code

```
(?:.*?\s?start(?<!$).*\b|(?<!.)start|^\w+start)
```

Results returns

> Test 23/25: It shouldn't match end start end start end start end start.

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ui5Hfr/1)

**Should be matched**

ssstarttt line

estart

start

aa start end start

**Should not be matched**

line_end start

end start end start end start end start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the text start should be there but the text end should not be before start, one option is to use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not `end`

```
^(?:(?!end).)*start.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!end).` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not end and match any character
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `start.*` Match start followed by any character 0+ times

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jSa7yP/2)

Comment: Test 17/25: It should match aaa start end start. By now you should be wondering if you have to anchor it to ^. And if you do anchor it, how to tell in a lookahead if it's before start. Try to make your pattern match character by character from the start, and to make it fail if it encounters end. Hint: /(?!end)./